# The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely, does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n_k}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely

and $a_{n_k}$ is sub sequence of $a_n$

does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n_k}$ also always converge ?

Since I failed to found any counter-example, 
and the only connection between absolutely convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n_k}$ in my textbook is this theorem: 
the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely iif the series of positive and negative members of $a_n$ converges,
I concluded that my proof must be somehow connected to this theorem.

In this stage I arrived to the dead-end.

Could you please give me some hint how to deal with this question ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. Since $\{n_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq \{n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, we see that

$$\sum_k \left|a_{n_k}\right| \le \sum_n |a_n| < \infty$$

So the relevant sum is, in fact, absolutely convergent.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\sum_k |a_{n_k}|\le \sum_n |a_n| $?

Comment: @user97484 You're adding up *fewer* positive things, so you get a smaller answer.

Comment: @user97484 You can prove it rigorously as follows: Take any arbitrary k, consider the sum of $|a_{n_i}|$ upto k, then take $n=n_k$, then it is less than the sum of $|a_i|$ upto n, which is less than the sum of $|a_n|$ over all n. This inequality is true for all k, so by order limit theorem it also holds for the infinite sum